# Make a Border Appear on only the Last Row of a Tablix in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, border, ssrs-tablix

I have a Tablix table object that is grouped by column invoiceNumber. The number of rows in the table is not static. I want a bottom border only on the very last row of the table (so no borders between the middle rows.)

On the last cell I have a custom function in the Border property:

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("invoiceNumber") = COUNT(Fields!invoiceTotal.Value, "invoiceNumber"), "Solid", "None")

<TablixCell>
                                <CellContents>
                                  <Textbox Name="Textbox41">
                                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                    <Paragraphs>
                                      <Paragraph>
                                        <TextRuns>
                                          <TextRun>
                                            <Value>=Fields!invoiceTotal.Value</Value>
                                            <Style />
                                          </TextRun>
                                        </TextRuns>
                                        <Style />
                                      </Paragraph>
                                    </Paragraphs>
                                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox10</rd:DefaultName>
                                    <Style>
                                      <Border>
                                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                                        <Style>=IIF(ROWNUMBER("invoiceNumber") = COUNT(Fields!invoiceTotal.Value, "invoiceNumber"), "Solid", "None")</Style>
                                      </Border>
                                      <TopBorder>
                                        <Style>None</Style>
                                      </TopBorder>
                                      <BottomBorder>
                                        <Style>None</Style>
                                      </BottomBorder>
                                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                    </Style>
                                  </Textbox>
                                  <rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
                                </CellContents>
                              </TablixCell>
                            </TablixCells>
```

But the system still puts a border under every cell. Should I place the function somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: Just add a bottom border to the tablix instead of the row